# In iMovie 10, how do you trim the middle of background audio?

Tags: audio, imovie, macos

I'm using iMovie 10.1.12 on Mac Mojave.  I have set an audio clip for some background music.  I was wondering if I could remove the middle of part of that clip.  I left clicked where I wanted to begin deleting, held the mouse down and slid the selector the right where I wanted to delete.  Then I right clicked and selected "Delete."  However, this is what happened

[image]

So when I play my movie, now there is a big silent gap where the Delete section was gone.  I don't want that.  I want the audio to seamlessly continue without a blank clip.  How do I (if possible) edit my audio so the deleted section disappears, but the rest of the audio continues to play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now there’s a gap in the background audio which you achieved by deleting your selection, drag the audio on the right towards the left so that the right edge of the left audio meets the left edge of the right audio.